# High number of xcodebuild processes get created when I click RUN

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcodebuild

XCODE version: 4.6.2

This is what happens when I click on RUN.

Message: "Running 1 of 1 custom shell scripts"  and the progress bar just halts.
Then just creates a lot of xcodebuild processes(I can see the processes getting spawned in Activity monitor). 
I quit XCODE from Activity monitor, but still the xcodebuild processes keep getting created.

As a background my app had a few warnings before i hit the RUN button in XCODE. Any clue how I can debug this without restarting my Mac everytime?

Comment: I think it is the problem of cacheing have you clean your derived data from xcode??

Comment: "Running 1 of 1 custom shell scripts" means you have linked a custom script with your project and whenever you build/run your project, your script also builds which takes time.. Have you attached a script on purpose in your project??

Comment: @Divz I cleaned the cache from DerivedData directory, but still I am getting the issue.

Comment: @Salman There are a few external libraries I am using in the project, incidentally this project was running fine a few weeks back!